# Route all traffic with iptables to external proxy

Tags: iptables

i would like to route all http/https/other ports traffic which is coming from pc1 to pc2, pc2 should route that to an external proxy that I would like to be able to set at pc2.

my current config is:
pc1 (eth0 / 192.168.0.1, Gateway: 192.168.0.2) -> pc2 (eth0  / 192.168.0.2) 
pc2 has to nics, eth0 and eth1. eth1 is the WAN connection.
in summary, eth1 @pc2 should be able to route incoming traffic from eth0 to a proxy server.

what I've tried:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o eth1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to proxy:3128
```

i'm able to ping pc2, but that was it unfortunately already. I'm new with iptables, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is pc2 acting as a gateway for pc1? (In other words, does it need to NAT the traffic passing through it?)

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide about s[etting up a transparent proxy with squid](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html) that seems like it might have some useful information.  It seems to have some different methods that could be adapted to solve your problem.

Most OS distributions also have guides and tutorials for using iptables and routing as well as the particular semantics for your OS of choice.  I have used the guides with [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) and [CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) in the past and they were very helpful when I was first learning to use iptables.